# Django model created DateTimeField & now difference

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm, model

I need data from MYSQL table using Django model ORM.

How can I get **Query Set** having data filtered on the bases of **difference** for created(DateTimeField) and now.

Here created is table column and now is MYSQL NOW();

My Use Case is to get rows those were created 7 days OR 168 hours ago.

Comment: Please add your model and any attempts you have made at the queryset to the question

Comment: Whenever you create a new Object from said model, just add a DataTimeField variable and set the default to the exact date, then whenever you're sifting thru said queryset, use that key to sort dates?

Comment: @IainShelvington https://github.com/edx/edx-platform/blob/master/common/djangoapps/student/models.py#L1213

Comment: When you say "7 days ago" do you mean "all rows created _exactly_ 7 days ago", "all rows created _more_ than 7 days ago" or "all rows created on the day that is 7 days ago"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `created__lte` searches for rows where `created` is less than or equal to a given date

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

...

CourseEnrollment.objects.filter(created__lte=(datetime.now() - timedelta(days=7)))
```